# Battery indicator icon showing charging even though not plugged in

Tags: battery, indicator

Battery indicator showing as plugged in, although it is not. When I plug it in, it shows correctly. When I unplug it goes back to showing as plugged in but discharging.
See screen shots

This happens quite often though I cannot reproduce it without any consistency. If I reboot it corrects itself.

Any ideas what to look for?

**Incorrect Message and icon when NOT plugged in**
[image: Message and icon when unplugged]

.
.
.

**Correct message and icon when plugged in**
[image: Message and icon when plugged in]

Operating System: Kubuntu 22.10
KDE Plasma Version: 5.25.5
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.98.0
Qt Version: 5.15.6
Kernel Version: 5.19.0-29-generic (64-bit)
Graphics Platform: X11
Processors: 16 × 12th Gen Intel® Core™ i7-1260P
Memory: 15.3 GiB of RAM
Graphics Processor: Mesa Intel® Graphics
Manufacturer: LG Electronics
Product Name: 14ZB90Q-G.AAC6U1
System Version: 0.1

Comment: This may actually be a fault in the battery rom. So maybe discharge it fully (i.e. disable any sleep on critical and let it run out) https://forum.manjaro.org/t/battery-icon-is-constantly-in-charging-mode/27605/23